# How is the redemption right on delisting of underlying shares held by holder in the convertible bond valued?

Tags: valuation, convertible-bond

As title, If there is no delisting constraint, then I can treat the redemption right as the put right on the convertible bond.

If there is redemption right on delisting, what is the conventional method to value the redemption right on delisting of underlying shares held by the holder in the convertible bonds? How is the delisting catered in the valuation? Is there any reference to discuss the valuation of convertible bonds with such redmeption right? Thanks.